# Can't access store from Vuex [Quasar]

Tags: vue.js, state, vuex, store, quasar

I'm trying Quasar for the first time and trying to use the Vuex with modules but I can't access the $store property nor with ...mapState. I get the following error 'Cannot read property 'logbook' of undefined' even though I can see that the promise logbook exists on Vue Devtools. [Print from Devtools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLmmU.png)

Here is my store\index.js

```js
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';
import logbook from './logbook';

Vue.use(Vuex);
export default function (/* { ssrContext } */) {
  const Store = new Vuex.Store({
    modules: {
      logbook,
    },
    strict: process.env.DEV,
  });
  return Store;
}
```

Here is the component

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h3>RFID</h3>
      <q-btn @click="logData"
             label="Save"
             class="q-mt-md"
             color="teal"
      ></q-btn>
      <q-table
        title="Logbook"
        :data="data"
        :columns="columns"
        row-key="uid"
      />
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex';

export default {
  name: 'RFID',
  mounted() {
    this.getLogbookData();
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('logbook', ['getLogbookData']),
    ...mapGetters('logbook', ['loadedLogbook']),
    ...mapState('logbook', ['logbookData']),
    logData: () => {
      console.log(this.loadedLogbook);
    },
  },
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>

</style>
```

Here is the state.js

```js
export default {
  logbookData: [],
};
```

[Error that I get on the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MAjs.png)

**Update:** Solved the problem by refactoring the way I declared the function. I changed from:

```js
logData: () => { console.log(this.loadedLogbook); }
```

to

```js
logData () { console.log(this.loadedLogbook); }
```

Comment: It seems like you're missing `namespaced: true` inside Store object

Answer (score 1):

Check the `.quasar/app.js` file. Is there a line similar to `import createStore from 'app/src/store/index'`, and the store is later exported with the app in that same file?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your input. The problem was with the way I declared the function. I changed from:

`logData: () => { console.log(this.loadedLogbook); }`

to

`logData () { console.log(this.loadedLogbook); }`

and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I think you confused all the mapx functions.

...mapState and ...mapGetters provide computed properties and should be handled like this

```
export default {
  name: 'RFID',
  data() {
    return {

    };
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getLogbookData();
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapGetters('logbook', ['loadedLogbook']),
    ...mapState('logbook', ['logbookData']),
  }
  methods: {
    ...mapActions('logbook', ['getLogbookData']),
    logData: () => {
      console.log(this.loadedLogbook);
    },
  }
};
```